# C/Python Extensions as part of package

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, cpython

I am building a python extension with the following hierarchy

```
setup.py
foopackage/
    __init__.py
    core.c
    const.py
    bar.py
```

where core.c is a C/Python extension.

setup.py defines the extension as follows:

```
ext_modules = [ Extension("foopackage.core",
                          glob("foopackage/*.c"),
                          language = "c",
                          extra_compile_args = ["-O0"],
                         )
              ]
```

in core.c I define the init as follows:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC
initcore(void) {
   PyObject *m;
   m = Py_InitModule("core", core_methods);
   if (m == NULL)
      return;
}
```

Let's suppose the `python setup.py build` creates a folder `build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/foopackage` containing the following hierarchy:

```
foopackage/
    __init__.py
    core.so
    const.py
    bar.py
```

when I am in build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7 and do `python` then `import foopackage.core` it works fine, however when I am elsewhere and do `PYTHONPATH=<full path to root>/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7 python` then `import foopackage.core` I get the following error:

`ImportError: No module named foopackage.core`

I can still import `foopackage.const` and `foopackage.bar`in both cases

Comment: What directory are you exactly in when you get the import error? Are you in the project root dir (where your `setup.py` and `foopackage` are)? If yes, it is the directory where the import will fail, all other dirs should still work with `PYTHONPATH` set as you described. If you want the import to work from the project root dir, a quick and dirty solution would be copying `core.so` from `build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/foopackage` to `foopackage`, so it is placed aside `core.c`. I can turn this comment into an answer and explain the problem in more detail, if you are interested.